# Responsive design: background image button

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image

I'm quite frustrated about a responsive site that I must create.
I was wondering about my buttons which have a background image (which is changed on hover). I would really like to keep them as css background images instead of using the img html tag.
I use this CSS for one of my buttons:

```
 a.projects 
 {
    background-image: url('css-images/projects.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
  }
```

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My site</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="menu">
           <ul class="nav">
                <li>
                         <div class="yellow-bar"></div>
                     <a href="#" class="projects" ></a>
                </li>
                <li> .... </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem is that the image is invisible. I suspect that this is because there is no content. But I don't want to add any content or assign some fixed height because my purpose is responsiveness!
I also have some other images that I use background css with no content that I want to apply this (the div with class "yellow-bar" ).
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are forced to give a size to your button.

You can give it a `min-height/min-width`. Maybe 40px for exemple. I did an analyse about responsive design and it is a recommended size for button.

```
a.projects 
 {
    min-width: 40px;
    min-height: 40px;
  }
```

Look at this presentation which speaks about it (slide 10) : http://www.slideshare.net/Developpeurs/web202-touch-en-html5-js